# How does Type Deduction work in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference

I'm trying to broaden my mind by learning Haskell.

My self-inflicted homework was to build a clock-tick generator which would give me Poisson-distributed intervals, and the end result (after a long struggle, I admit) was this:

```
import System.Random
poissonStream :: ( Ord r, Random r, Floating r, RandomGen g) => r -> r -> r -> g -> [r]
poissonStream rate start limit gen 
        | next > limit = [] 
        | otherwise     = next:(poissonStream rate next limit newGen)
        where  (rvalue, newGen) = random gen
               next = start - log(rvalue) / rate
```

But there are two things (at least) I don't understand:

Why do I need "`Ord r`" as well as "`Floating r`"? (I would have expected some kind of automatic inheritance: "Floating" implies "Ord".)

By what path is the implied type definition "`rvalue :: Float`" achieved? 
In GHCi I get what I would have expected:

```
*Main System.Random> let (rvalue, newGen) = random (mkStdGen 100)
<interactive>:1:23:
    Ambiguous type variable `t' in the constraint:
      `Random t' arising from a use of `random' at <interactive>:1:23-43
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
```

*rvalue* is a loose cannon which I have to tie down:

```
*Main System.Random> let (rvalue, newGen) = random (mkStdGen 100) :: (Float, StdGen)
*Main System.Random> rvalue
0.18520793
```

Please be gentle with a Haskell n00b.

Comment: IMHO if this is just self-learning I wouldn't tag it as homework. Homework questions imply a highly artificial problem and will generally change the kind of answer you get (far more of a hint than laying it out for you), unless that's what you prefer.

Comment: @cletus: Thanks for the observation. I thought it better to flag this as an exercise, rather than a real-world problem, up front.

Comment: I would tag it "hobby" or "self-learning" rather than "homework." "Homework" doesn't imply "not real world" so much as "Don't really give me an answer."

Comment: @Chuck, @cletus: OK, thank you. I've removed the hw tag.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why do I need "Ord r" as well as "Floating r"? (I would have expected some kind of automatic inheritance: "Floating" implies "Ord".)

`Floating` is supposed to classify all floating-point numbers, including complex ones. There is no ordering for complex numbers. You could use `RealFloat` instead of `Floating`, which implies `Ord`.

> By what path is the implied type definition "rvalue :: Float" achieved?

Well you can infer that from the context in which `rvalue` is used. It's the argument to `log`, and

```
:t log
```

gives

```
log :: (Floating a) => a -> a
```

so `rvalue` must be in the `Floating` class (so it will be "some type in the `Floating` typeclass, not precisely `Float`). Further, the result of `log` is of the same type as its input and is used in a computation with `start` and `rate` and is compared with `limit` which are all of type `r`, so `rvalue` will be of `r` (which is suitable because `r` is of `Floating` as well).

In your GHCi example, there is no more context. Type

```
 :t random (mkStdGen 100)
```

This gives you

```
random (mkStdGen 100) :: (Random a) => (a, StdGen)
```

GHCi doesn't know what type to fill in for `a` here. It only knows it's got to be in typeclass `Random`.

Comment: Yes, of course. It hadn't occurred to me that Floating might include complex floats; and thank you for the RealFloat pointer.

I *did* understand the behaviour in GHCi; I was just using that to contrast with the apparently more liberal behaviour of my function.

Thank you very much for a clear answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Haskell, Ord and Floating are independent or [orthogonal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality#Computer_science) concepts. Perhaps you were assuming that Floating only referred to very specific types, like Double and Float (this would be the case in most other languages)?

As Rudiger pointed out, there are types that are instances of the class Floating that are not Ord because there is no ordering for certain float types, like Complex. Another example besides Complex numbers would be vectors, for which you may define these Floating functions, but not any kind of sensible Ord-ering.

Remember that type classes just specify the set of functions (like an interface in Java or C#, if that's a helpful way of thinking about it) that must be defined for a type **a**; to be Ord, a type **a** just needs comparison operators, and to be an instance of Floating, a type **a** just needs to implement Fractional and have the functions pi, exp, sqrt, log, sin, cos, ... defined for them. That's all Floating means, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I appreciate the concept of orthogonality; I was just applying it to much-too-small a concept space.